# Editing entered text on double click using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made Todo app using react. On clicking enter the todo gets added in array, then on click on entered todo the todo gets stricked-off. Now i am facing problem to edit the entered todo. I want when i double click the entered todo, it converts into editing mode and then i can edit the todo n save it on enter keypress. My code goes like this:

```js
    class App extends React.Component {

  

constructor(){

    super();
    this.state={
      todo:[]
    };
  };
  
  entertodo(keypress){
    var Todo=this.refs.inputodo.value;
    if( keypress.charCode == 13 )
  
    {
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo.concat({Value:Todo, checked:false, editing:false})
      });
      this.refs.inputodo.value=null;
    };
  };
  todo(todo,i){
    return (
      <li className={todo.checked===true? 'line':'newtodo'}>
        <div onClick={this.todoCompleted.bind(this, i)}>
          <input type="checkbox" className="option-input checkbox" checked={todo.checked} />
          <div key={todo.id}  className="item">
            {todo.Value}
            <span className="destroy" onClick={this.remove.bind(this, i)}>X</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  };
  
  remove(i){
    this.state.todo.splice(i,1)
    this.setState({todo:this.state.todo})
  };
  todoCompleted(i){
     var todo=this.state.todo;
     todo[i].checked =todo[i].checked? false:true;
       this.setState({
         todo:this.state.todo
       });
  
   };
  allCompleted=()=>{
    var todo = this.state.todo;
    var _this = this
    todo.forEach(function(item) {
      item.className = _this.state.finished ? "newtodo" : "line"
      item.checked = !_this.state.finished
    })
    this.setState({todo: todo, finished: !this.state.finished})
  };
    render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1 id='heading'>todos</h1>
          <div className="lines"></div>
          <div>
            <input type="text" ref= "inputodo" onKeyPress={this.entertodo.bind(this)}className="inputodo"placeholder='todos'/>
            <span onClick={this.allCompleted}id="all">^</span>
          </div>
          <div className="mainapp">
            <ul className="decor">
              {this.state.todo.map(this.todo.bind(this))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
     

 

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
    .line {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: red;
}
.newtodo{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying something similar, so [this gist](https://gist.github.com/c0d0g3n/ed630ea7a24ac8a3c4a09faab77aa7ec) might help you on the right track. I think you're especially interested the `handleClick` method. It **debounces** received click events. Then you can listen for a certain amount of consecutive clicks, like I did on [line 33](https://gist.github.com/c0d0g3n/ed630ea7a24ac8a3c4a09faab77aa7ec#file-editablecontainer-jsx-L33).

**However, the transition between view and edit seems to be quite slow** (maybe I did something wrong :shrug:) **, so if editing should happen frequently, it might be better to fake this behavior with css.***

- Style an input type to look like ordinary text, then `onFocus`, style it like a field.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for the click events called onDoubleClick={this.handler} at this point in time.

Answer (score 1):

you may use the component

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import { useState } from 'react'

const inputValue = (e: any): string => e.target.value

function isEnterOrEscapeKeyEvent(event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    return event.key === 'Enter' || event.key === 'Escape'
}

const EditOnDblClick = () => {
    const [isEditing, setisEditing] = useState(false)
    const [text, settext] = useState('yoga chitta')

    const onEditEnd = () => {
        setisEditing(false)
    }

    return isEditing ? (
        <input
            value={text}
            className="bg-transparent border-2 border-black border-solid"
            onKeyDown={(event) => {
                if (isEnterOrEscapeKeyEvent(event)) {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    event.stopPropagation()
                    onEditEnd()
                }
            }}
            onChange={_.flow(inputValue, settext)}
            onBlur={onEditEnd}
            autoFocus
        />
    ) : (
        <div className="select-none" onDoubleClick={() => setisEditing(true)}>
            {text}
        </div>
    )
}

export default EditOnDblClick
```

Note: Classes are from tailwindcss